# Como esconder carpertas en un servidor web

Tags: php, html5, web, aplicación-web

Estoy montando mi sitio web, tengo una sección de login, pero si pongo la url completa a la página siguiente despues del login se está al alcance, aunque no tiene datos, ya que uso PHP por medio de POST, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma dentro de mi servidor para que aunque se tenga la url no pueda acceder sin antes hacer login??

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Investiga sobre algo que se llama .htaccess, eso te servirá para lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 2):

Para controlar cualquier acceso de forma sencilla, solo debes seguir dos pasos.

1.- Al hacer login crear una variable de sesión.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
// comprobación de login
// ...
if($login === true){
    $_SESSION['user'] = $userId;
}
```

2.- Al acceder a cualquier url protegida, comprobar si tiene la sesión activa mediante la verificación de que la variable de user existe y tiene algún valor válido.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location:login-url.php");
}
```

El punto 2 debería ir en el inicio de cada archivo que tiene que estar protegido.

Esto es lo más sencillo, de aquí en adelante se puede complicar tanto como sea necesario.

Comment: faltaría agregar un logout.php donde se unsetea y destruye la session

Comment: @aloMalbarez me he ceñido a la pregunta, por eso no me he extendido más en la respuesta. Gracias por comentar.